# How can I dynamically set the Foreground to a theme resource in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I have a TextBlock and I want to dynamically set the Foreground based on a condition. But I'd like the Foreground to be a theme resource.

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact.DisplayName}" Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource isNewConverter}}" ></TextBlock>`

```
public class IsNewConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {            
        IMessage message = value as IMessage;

        if (message == null || message.IsNew == false) return null;

        return SystemAccentColor; // where and how do I get the current SystemAccentColor brush?

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`return new SolidColorBrush(
    (Color)Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"]);`

You can probably also create some kind of "SystemAccentBrush" in your resources and set its color to SystemAccentColor, that way you won't have to create new brush object each time your converter is called.

There are also several system brushes like `SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush` which might be what you need? So you can do:

`return (Brush)Application.Current
    .Resources["SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"];`

Comment: It's strange because the Application.Current.Resources has no items in it, but this still works. Thanks!

Comment: Will it not create problem, when you have two different values for a key in light & dark theme dictionary and default windows mode is pointed to dark, but you start your app in light mode. In this case my app is taking the value from dark theme dictionary instead of taking from light theme dictionary.